# Error on Rails S | Rails Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a newbie in rails. I installed Rails(4) and Ruby using RVM.

I get an error whenever I run `rails s` or `rails server` on a different terminal.

It says

```
The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rails
```

It only works on the first terminal I used to install rails on.

The left terminal is the one where i installed rails on
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDy7k.png]

Comment: have you added the rvm path in .bashrc? Also, do not install any gems using 'sudo'

Comment: Did you install rails under a particular gemset?

Comment: I used rvm to setup rails.  @prasad.surase thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you havent added the rvm path in bashrc or bash_profile

```
/home/username/.bashrc
/home/username/.bash_profile
```

Add

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

and

```
source .bashrc
```

Comment: @olleh when you open a new terminal, rvm needs to get loaded. Specifying the above code will initialize the rvm which will load a ruby version. the gems are installed under a specific ruby version. ie if you install rails 4.1 under ruby 2.1, it(rails 4.1) wont be accessible under ruby 2.0. hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your terminal likely isn't set to be a login terminal, so RVM isn't being setup correctly on new terminal instances.

See https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal for how to configure your terminal as a login terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [gemsets](http://rvm.io/gemsets)? You can think of each gemset as an independent, compartmentalized "environment" that houses your rails installations.

If you've already installed rails under a gemset, are you making sure your new terminal window's environment is [using the gemset](http://rvm.io/gemsets/using) that you installed rails on? When you open a new terminal window, it won't know which gemset to use, unless you configure it to use some default gemset. You can use the gemset you created by doing:

```
$ rvm use <YOUR_GEMSETNAME>
```

If you don't know/remember what gemsets you created, you can list them with the following command. Try using this command on the terminal that worked. It'll indicate which gemset you're using (then you can use that gemset name with the `use` command above):

```
$ rvm gemset list_all
```

This [Rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec-install_ruby) does a good job of giving step by step instructions on installing ruby and rails with rvm properly. Just remember that with every new terminal that you open, you have to make sure you're using that gemset.